# Cannot deploy new containers when using custom DNS

Tags: dns, docker, proxmox

I reset my proxmox server. The first thing I put back online was my AdGuard home DNS server. But when trying to deploy other containers I got an error message. I tried different containers but they all give the same as error message, namely:

```
Error Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.53:53: read udp 127.0.0.1:49692-&gt;127.0.0.53:53: i/o timeout
```

Can anyone help me out what is wrong? Is it even a good idea to run AdGuard in a docker instance with other services on the same IP, or should I run a container or VM on my proxmox with its own IP only for running AdGuard?

Thanks